# How to make background-image size height always equal what the image height needs to be for full width image?

Tags: html, css

How do I make an image always have the same crop height. As in on this site http://deliciousproductions.com.au/ the div is 420px high. But the image extends further.

Here's the div

```
<div class="dpsplash">
</div>
```

css

```
.dpsplash {
    background-image: url('/img/banner1.png');  
    background-size: auto 800px;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

So what this does is make the image height so that when you resize the page horizontally it doesn't shift the point where you crop the image for the div height, but instead extends the width. Buuuut we run into a problem because I have to guess the image height for a full width drawing on bigger resolutions where the image won't be shorter than 400px if displayed at full width, because if a 2500x1200 image is displayed at full width on a phone, it's gonna end before the div does, looking ugly.

I feel like in maths/javascript it should be that [(current page width)/(image width)] * (image height) = (the height it needs to be) or x, so the background-size style should be `background-size: auto (that formula from above?);`

I know basically no Javascript, it's so confusing but I understand logic arguments.

Comment: your explanation is more confusing than question! Do you want a solution, where the height of your background image, changes in proportion to its width, but keeping the same aspect ratio ?

Comment: yes but in regards to the initial draw size. Buut I don't actually think my question makes sense. Because the problem I had was that I'm doing my testing on a 1080p monitor, so if I pick a height which makes the image full width on my monitor, it will stay at the same crop height point for when the page goes smaller, it won't look like that on larger monitors because the width will be less than the screen width. But all I can bassically do is choose the maximum screen width I want it to work with and go from there

Comment: Did you mean: `background-size:cover;`?

Comment: + comment. But say on a 4k monitor, I still want the image to be full width, okay I guess what I'm saying is that if the screen resolution is 1080p, the image height is so that the image width is 100% and any lower screen resolution, the height value stays the same so that the bottom crop point is the same and the image just gets wider. But on higher than 1080p resolution monitors the image needs to say full screen, because even though it's 4k it could still be a 27inch monitor compared to a 1080p monitor. So the div should really be a % height right.. hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `background-size: cover;`? What it does ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)):

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

Comment: yes thank-you, this is what I need for the resolutions above 1080p. I'll write some javascript to replace the style from .dpsplash {
 background-image: url('/img/banner1.png'); 
 background-size: auto 950.4;
 height: 400px;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
} to .dpsplash {
 background-image: url('/img/banner1.png'); 
 background-size: cover;
 height: 400px;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

when you scroll. Actually I just took the background-position: center-top; out and it resizes well :)

Answer (score 2):

Yea, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking and your comment didn't particularly clear that up for me.

All I took out of this is that you want the image to look similar or the same on higher resolution screens? For one, if you want to test that you can zoom out on your browser to get an estimate on what it would look like on higher dpi screens. There's also a mobile emulator as part of Chrome's devtools that will simulate higher dpi's.

As to your question, if the question is how can you maintain the aspect ratio as well as keep the image at 100% the width past 1080p, a simple solution would be to add a media query that forces width 100% past a screen width of 1920 pixels. Which would look like `width: 100%;`. If that doesn't look exactly right to you, you could try setting the width past 100% at a value like 150% so it takes up a similar sized portion of the screen as earlier. If that is not your question and you want the image to scale with the dpi, experiment with the values `vh` and `vw` which will do just this. They stand for viewport height and width. You can also set the maximum width, height, vw, and vh with `max-height/width` and `vmin/max`